# One liner to listen via netcat

Tags: bash, shell

I had this one liner in the terminal shell:

```
 while true; do echo foo | nc -l 3000 done;
```

I just want to keep listening on port 3000. But it seems like syntactically for bash to work I need a newline?

```
 while true; do 
     echo foo | nc -l 3000 
 done;
```

is there some way to do this on one line? what's happening here?

Comment: Put the last `;` before the `done` since it represents a newline

Comment: Why is the `echo` needed here?

Comment: using `echo` was just verbatim what I had, it's a better practice to show exactly what was causing the problem as long as it's not too much code. and in this case `echo foo` is the message being sent to netcat server clients.

Answer (score 1):

Read the shell (e.g. `bash`) manual page to learn the syntax of the commands!
The "problem" has nothing to do with `netcat`.

The usual syntax for a `while` loop is

```
while sleep 1
do
    echo "I want to read 'man bash'"
done
```

But you can write it as `while sleep 1; do echo "I want to read 'man bash'"; done`.

Or as the manual puts it: `while list-1; do list-2; done`

Comment: yes but if you are at the terminal prompt, harder to use multiple lines

Comment: Would you care to accept one of the answers given?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a semi-colon:

```
 while true; do echo foo | nc -l 3000; done;
 # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~
```